# Column name as a query parameter Spring JPA

Tags: java, postgresql

I am using Spring JPA for show all duplicates in column or only unique values in colums. But I have many columns and need choose the columns.
In Postgres I use query:

```
SELECT * FROM table_test ou WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_test inr WHERE inr.col1 = ou.col1) > 1;
```

Repository:

```
    @Query(value = FIND_DUPLICATES, nativeQuery = true)
    List<Product> findDuplicates();
```

But need change name of column (@Param). I tried:

```
SELECT * FROM table_test ou WHERE 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_test inr WHERE inr.?1= ou.?1) > 1;
```

doesn't work.

Comment: See : https://chartio.com/learn/databases/how-to-find-duplicate-values-in-a-sql-table/

Comment: @NikolaiShevchenko yes and no. My value is only columnName in query. Here I see columnsName and value what I need to find. Or I can't implementation it.

Comment: You can't pass column **names** as parameters. Parameters are only for **values**.